# Redirecting to old site to new site using .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns

I’m changing my site url from invadingholland.com to accidentallydutch.com. I’ve already migrated the site and now have it in the two locations. I’m trying to set up redirects from all posts and pages on the old site to the new one (using .htaccess file of the old site). The redirect is not working but nothing is breaking either.

There was some redirecting code already in there (in two places) for the plugin that handles the http to https redirects on my old site (added a few years ago). I guess that is interfering in some way or I’m adding my code in wrong. If anyone can tell me how to set this up I would be very grateful. Thanks.

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Forced Redirect
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN HTTPS Forced Redirect" and 
# "END HTTPS Forced Redirect" are dynamically generated, and should 
# only be modified via the filters. Any changes to the directives between 
# these markers will be overwritten.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.*)https://accidentallydutch.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END HTTPS Forced Redirect
```

---

```
# Use PHP7.2 as default
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php
# BEGIN Really Simple SSL Redirect 5.3.0
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)https://accidentallydutch.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END Really Simple SSL Redirect
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I assume the first code block is the contents of the `.htaccess` file at the old host (odl domain) and the second `.htaccess` file is at the new host?

Comment: Hi MrWhite. They are both from the .htaccess of the old site. The first block is just nearer the top of the file and the second is nearer the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> RewriteRule (.*)https://accidentallydutch.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

You are missing a *space* between arguments. ie. `(.*)<here>https://accid...`. The net result is that the above will do nothing because the regex never matches. However, you have also kept the *condition* that checks the HTTPS status (part of the HTTP to HTTPS rule), so this would only redirect HTTP (not HTTPS).

Assuming the new domain points to a different server then you don't need any of this at the old host. Delete the contents of the existing `.htaccess` file and use a simple mod_alias `Redirect` directive instead:

```
# .htaccess at the old host/domain

# Redirect everything to the new domain
Redirect 301 / https://example.new/
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix matching and everything after the match is passed through to the target. eg. `https://example.old/foo/bar` is redirected to `https://example.new/foo/bar`.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

At the new host...

```
# BEGIN Really Simple SSL Redirect 5.3.0
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)https://accidentallydutch.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END Really Simple SSL Redirect
```

You are missing a `<space>` again, as mentioned above. However, this section is maintained by the "Really Simple SSL" plugin. There's no real need to change it (and any changes you do make are likely to be overwritten by the plugin).